# Modeling satellite's orbit around earth in python?

Tags: python, physics, motion

I've been following along with a [tutorial](https://fiftyexamples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gravity.html), which models Earth, Venus, and the Sun. The code runs just fine. However, I'm trying to model a satellite's orbit about the earth, where the earth is the center of its "universe" at position (0,0). I'm running into issues as my satellite flies off on a tangent but I'm not sure why.

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
class Planet():
    def __init__(self,vx=0.0,vy=0.0,px=0.0,py=0.0,mass=0.0):
        self.vx=vx
        self.vy=vy
        self.px=px
        self.py=py
        self.mass = mass
        
def attract(p1,p2,grav=6.67428e-11):
    dx = p1.px - p2.px
    dy = p1.py - p2.py
    d = np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
    force = (grav * p1.mass * p2.mass)/d**2
    theta = math.atan2(dy,dx)
    fx = math.cos(theta)*force
    fy = math.sin(theta)*force
    return fx,fy

def loop(bodies,epochs=10,timestep=10):
    # compute forces
    forces = {}
    for i in range(0,len(bodies)):
        total_fx = 0
        total_fy = 0
        for j in range(0,len(bodies)):
            if i == j:
                continue
            fx,fy = attract(bodies[i],bodies[j])
            total_fx += fx
            total_fy += fy
        forces[i] = (total_fx,total_fy)
    #apply forces 
    sat_tups = []
    for e in range(epochs):
        for i in range(len(bodies)):
            if bodies[i] == satellite:
                sat_tups.append((bodies[i].px,bodies[i].py))            
            fx,fy = forces[i]
            bodies[i].vx += (fx/bodies[i].mass*timestep)
            bodies[i].vy += (fy/bodies[i].mass*timestep)
            bodies[i].px += bodies[i].vx*timestep
            bodies[i].py += bodies[i].vy*timestep  

    return sat_tups
        
 

earth = Planet(mass = 5.9742 * 10**24)
satellite = Planet(mass= 3000.0, px= 1414.0, py= 1414.0, vx=2300.0,vy=2300.0)
tups = loop(bodies=[earth,satellite])

tups
>>>
[(1414.0, 1414.0),
 (7050856421.79636, 7050856421.79636),
 (21152543437.38908, 21152543437.38908),
 (42305062460.77817, 42305062460.77817),
 (70508413491.96361, 70508413491.96361),
 (105762596530.9454, 105762596530.9454),
 (148067611577.72357, 148067611577.72357),
 (197423458632.2981, 197423458632.2981),
 (253830137694.66898, 253830137694.66898),
 (317287648764.83624, 317287648764.83624)]
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. Perhaps, centering Earth at (0,0) simply isn't going to work. Or perhaps these laws of physics are only applicable when bodies are of relatively similar sizes (else more intricate rules are at play.)

To answer this question, please address what is causing the satellite to fly off? (I would have guessed that it would crash into earth, not sling-shot away).

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  The initial debugging work is supposed to be your responsibility.  Since this is only a two-body problem, you should be able to compute one or two iterations of values on your own; ask us something more focused, such as "Why is the satellite's orbital velocity 100 times the problem value after 2 iterations?  My second motion equation *looks* correct, but the result is wrong."